# ASP.NET Core web application : upgrade to Angular 9 - error es2015 as esm2015

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I updated my ASP.NET Core web application (.NET Core 3.1) from Angular 8 to 9 with this Angular guide:

https://update.angular.io/#8.0:9.0

After this, I started the application and get the following error for many modules:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
>   Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015

and in the dev tools of the Browser I get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Strict mode code may not include a with statement

I don't find anything that helps on the web. Any ideas?

I build an example app for this issue. You can find it [here](https://github.com/cschulc/Asp.NetCoreAngular8to9)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution for this is you need to follow this guide https://jasontaylor.dev/asp-net-core-angular-9-upgrade/

1. First in your `main.ts` you need to remove the code 
   `export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';`
2. Update your npm start script to `echo Starting... && ng serve`

> `"start": "echo Starting... && ng serve"`

There is also a github issue raised to this

Reference: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34970#issuecomment-581838896